# Find the minimum value of $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (2-x_1-x_2)^2 + (2x_1-3x_2)^2}$

Tags: maxima-minima

This is a question from a practice workbook for a college entrance exam.

Find the minimum value of -
$$\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (2-x_1-x_2)^2 + (2x_1-3x_2)^2} \text{  where  } x_1,x_2 \in R$$

I think it will possibly involve the decomposition of this function into finding the minimum distance between two loci, possibly conic sections.
So I tried just simplifying -
$$=\sqrt{6x_1^2+11x_2^2-12x_1x_2-4x_1-4x_2+4}$$
Interestingly if you switch out $x_1, x_2$ with $x,y$ then the standard two degree polynomial that emerges has $\Delta \neq 0$ and $h^2<ab$ suggesting a ellipse (or a single point, or a no solution) I don't know what such a substitution actually means theoretically so I don't know what to from there.

Comment: Minimize the square

Comment: Um how? I can't seem to find any $(ax_1+bx_2 + c)^2 $which will agree with the variable terms.

Comment: Minimize $(x_1-x_2)^2 + (2-x_1-x_2)^2 + (2x_1-3x_2)^2$

Comment: The value $\sqrt{6x^2+11y^2-12xy-4x-4x+4}$ is minimized when is minimal $$f(x,y)=6x^2+11y^2-12xy-4x-4x+4.$$ There is exactly one stationary point satisfying $(f_x,f_y)=(0,0).$ It is $(x,y)=(-1/3,0).$ With the use of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test we find that it is a minimum.

Comment: @user376343: did you mean $-4x-\color{red}{4y}+4$?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 yes, it is a typo ... but I cannot edit my comment anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the expression given as distance between two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ in $\Bbb{R^3}$. So let us figure out what are $y_i$ and $z_i$. For example, we can take $y_1=2-x_1$ and $y_2=x_2$ and so on...

Consider the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ given by the vector equations
$$L_1: \mathbf{r}_1=\begin{bmatrix}t\\2-t\\2t\end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}}_{\color{red}{\mathbf{a}}}+t\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}}_{\color{red}{t\mathbf{b}}} \quad \text{ and } \quad L_2: \mathbf{r}_2=s\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}}_{\color{blue}{s\mathbf{d}}}$$
Then the **shortest** distance between these two lines is what you are looking for. Perhaps you can take it from here and since the lines are not parallel you can use [shortest distance between two skew lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance)

Some helpful details:

The unit normal vector $\vec{\mathbf{n}}=\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}\\\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}}\end{bmatrix}$ and if my calculations are correct then the minimum value is $\color{magenta}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}}}$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be interpreted as a LS problem: minimize the norm of vector $v$, with

$$ v = A\,x + b$$

With the matrix $A$ equal to :

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    2 & -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and the vector $b$ equal to :

$$ b = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    -2 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

The solution is provided by using the pseudo-inverse $A^+$ of the matrix $A$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
 = - A^+ b
$$

After some straightforward calculations, we get

$$
 A^+ = \frac{1}{30} \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 17 & 4 \\
    0 & 12 & -6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

And finally

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 = \frac{17}{15} \\[2ex]
x_2 = \frac{12}{15}
\end{cases}
$$

Then, the minimum value is equal to

$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{15}}
$$

The same as the previous answer!